# NSXML XML Parsing issue iOS

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, soap, xml-parsing

I know that there are plenty of questions that have been asked and answered and non of them pertain to my problem.

I am posting XML to a server and I get a response back. My problem is getting a specified key back from the response.

I am trying to list all Genders e.g Male, Female and their id's however when parsing the XML into text with NSXML I only get back the Female and ID 2 and I do not get back Male?

I have researched and tried to fix this issue but to no avail.

here is my code:

```
- (void)getGender {

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:app=\"http://app.ws.api.bells.wigroup.com/\">"
                             "<soap:Header/>\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<app:getAllGenders>\n"
                             "<request>\n"
                             "<apiCredentials>\n"
                             "<apiId>IPHONE_APP</apiId>\n"
                             "<sha1Password>8656cafcd71cbbfe773a0fdb6c422666a80e5b8f</sha1Password>\n"
                             "</apiCredentials>\n"
                             "<request>\n"
                             "</request>\n"
                             "</request>\n"
                             "</app:getAllGenders>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                             ];
    NSLog(@"Message%@",soapMessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.wigroup.co:8080/bells/AppWS"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //[theRequest addValue: @"http://" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;

        NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Login response XML:%@",str);


        // create and init NSXMLParser object
        XmlArrayParser *parser = [[XmlArrayParser alloc] initWithData:urlData];
        parser.rowElementName = @"return";
        parser.elementNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"response", @"responseCode", @"responseDesc", @"gendersList", nil];
        parser.attributeNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id", @"gender", nil];

        if ([parser.rowElementName isEqualToString:@"responseCode"] && _flag)
        {
            //read the value here
             NSLog(@"flagging");
        }

        // parsing...
        BOOL success = [parser parse];

        // test the result
        if (success)
        {
            NSMutableArray *loginAuth = [parser items];

            //        self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
            //        @"This is an array of dictionaries, one dictionary for each user:\n\n%@",
            //        [users description]];

           // NSDictionary *eventLocation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"response", nil];

            NSDictionary *loginResponse = [loginAuth objectAtIndex:0];         // this retrieves the first user
            NSString *userResponse = loginResponse[@"gendersList"];           // this retrieves that user's username in Xcode 4.5 and greater

            NSString *userRes = [loginResponse objectForKey:@"id"];

            NSString *test = [loginAuth description];

            NSLog(@"Returned Code loginResponse %@",loginResponse);
            NSLog(@"Returned Code userResponse %@ %@",userResponse, userRes);
            NSLog(@"Returned Code test %@",test);

            NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

            for (NSDictionary *defineXMLData in loginAuth) {

                NSNumber * responseCode = [defineXMLData objectForKey:@"responseCode"];
                NSArray * responseDEsc = [defineXMLData objectForKey:@"responseDesc"];
                NSArray * genderList = [defineXMLData objectForKey:@"gendersList"];
               // NSArray * gender = [defineJsonData objectForKey:@"gender"];

                NSLog(@"Genders%@", genderList);

                [array addObject: responseCode];
                [array addObject: responseDEsc];
                [array addObject: genderList];
                //[array addObject: gender];
                // [array addObject: vouchersUser];
            }

            label.numberOfLines = 2000; // for example
            label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
            NSString *output=[array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"XML Result: %@ ",output];

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            //            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
            //                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No errors - user count : %i", [[parser items] count]]
            //                                       delegate:nil
            //                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            //                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");

            //            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
            //                                        message:@"Error parsing document!"
            //                                       delegate:nil
            //                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            //                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    NSLog(@"test");

}
```

And the XML I get back from my nslog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getAllGendersResponse xmlns:ns2="http://app.ws.api.bells.wigroup.com/">
         <return>
            <responseCode>-1</responseCode>
            <responseDesc>Success</responseDesc>
            <response>
               <responseCode>-1</responseCode>
               <responseDesc>Success</responseDesc>
               <gendersList>
                  <gender>Male</gender>
                  <id>1</id>
               </gendersList>
               <gendersList>
                  <gender>Female</gender>
                  <id>2</id>
               </gendersList>
            </response>
```

Is only parsing:

```
{
gendersList = Female2;
responseCode = "-1";
responseDesc = Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not correctly pointed the problem. Your code parses the whole document, but you keep only the last items (last genderList, last responseCode, last responseDesc). Initialize an array and in your for loop add each dictionary to that array when parsed.